# system and fork calls are blocking the port 3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.4 . I am developing a plugin so I don't have too much of leeway.

In my controller I need to invoke a rake task. The rake task will take longer to finish so I am following the approach mentioned in [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background) which is

```
system "rake #{task} &"
```

This solution works great and everything is fine. I know this solution will not work on windows and I'm fine with that.

I started my server at port 3000. The controller was invoked which fired the rake task in the background. However if I ctrl +c my script/server and if I try to restart the server then I get this error.

Address already in use - bind(2) (Errno::EADDRINUSE)

Then I changed my code to do this

```
fork do
 system "rake #{task} &"
end
```

Still the same issue.

Does anyone how do I get around this problem of port 3000 getting blocked. Also any explanation of why rake task is blocking port 3000 would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [ruby-docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Process.html#M000955):

**Kernel.fork [{ block }] => fixnum or nil**

**Process.fork [{ block }] => fixnum or nil**

> Creates a subprocess. If a block is
>   specified, that block is run in the
>   subprocess, and the subprocess
>   terminates with a status of zero.
>   Otherwise, the fork call returns
>   twice, once in the parent, returning
>   the process ID of the child, and once
>   in the child, returning nil. The child
>   process can exit using Kernel.exit! to
>   avoid running any at_exit functions.
>   **The parent process should use Process.wait to collect the
>   termination statuses of its children
>   or use Process.detach to register
>   disinterest in their status;
>   otherwise, the operating system may
>   accumulate zombie processes.**

The thread calling fork is the only thread in the created child process. fork doesn‘t copy other threads.
Final solution based on comments below:

```
command = "rake #{task} #{args.join(' ')}" 
p1 = Process.fork { system(command) } 
Process.detach(p1)
```

Comment: Not working.

Revised code
  p1 = fork { system(command) }
    Process.detach(p1)

still getting address already in use

Comment: Just to make sure there are no loose ends, could you change fork to Process.fork?

Comment: same issue with Process.fork too.

Comment: Remove & at the end of your call.

Comment: Yeap that solved the problem. You should edit your answer and put this code as the final answer so that others could see it clearly.

    command =  "rake #{task} #{args.join(' ')}"
    p1 = Process.fork { system(command) }
    Process.detach(p1)